# Time taken to reach from one point to another in refraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, speed-of-light, time, refraction

According to Fermat's principle, path taken between two points by a ray of light is the path that can be traversed in the least time.

Suppose the source of light is point $(x_1, y_1)$ and speed of light in this medium is $v_1$ whereas the other point (destination) in the adjacent medium be $(x_2, y_2)$ and speed of light in the medium be $v_2$. It is given that $y_1 < 0$ and $y_2 > 0$ such that $y = 0$ is the interface between the two mediums.

By minimizing the time function we get Snell's law: $\displaystyle{\frac{v_1}{\sin \theta_1} = \frac{v_2}{\sin \theta_2}}$. But I wanted to know the minimized value of time taken to reach from $(x_1 , y_1)$ to $(x_2 , y_2)$. If the point of incidence on the interface of the two mediums be $(x , 0)$ then -

$$T(x)  = \frac{\sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + y_1^2}}{v_1} + \frac{\sqrt{(x - x_2)^2 + y_2^2}}{v_2} $$

where $ x_1 , y_1, x_2, y_2, v_1, v_2$ are constants.

> I differentiated $T(x)$ with respect to $x$ i.e.
>
> $$ \frac{dT}{dx}  = \frac{x- x_1}{v_1 \sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + y_1^2}} + \frac{x- x_2}{v_2 \sqrt{(x - x_2)^2 + y_2^2}} = 0$$
>
> But I was not able to find $x$ from the above equation and substitute in $T(x)$ to find its minimum value.

Comment: Minimise the optical path.

Comment: @Lelouch I think I will get the same equation if I try to minimize the optical path length. Refractive index for medium 1 $ \mu_1 = \frac{c}{v_1} $ and  for medium 2 $ \mu_2 = \frac{c}{v_2} $.  Since $d_1 =  \sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + y_1^2} $ and $d_2 =  \sqrt{(x - x_2)^2 + y_2^2} $ so minimum of $\mu_1 d_1 + \mu_2 d_2$ will give the original equation.

Comment: Cant you just solve your equation? Multiply by denominators, move one term to the other side and square both sides, move it back and simpllify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution from computer programming point of view would be to use a **ternary search** from the range $left = min(x_1,x_2)$ to $right = max(x_1, x_2)$ since the time function decreases and then increases so we could determine the minima.
I think a mathematical solution would be rigorous but if someone wants to contribute then it will be very useful as I was not able to find the answer on a large number of resources I checked out.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the expressions with the square roots in the denominator on opposite sides of the equation and square both sides you will see that you get a quartic equation for x. For quartic equations there are still formulae for the solutions which are, however, rather cumbersome. Therefore you should first check by doing the algebra if the resulting quartic equation can actually be transformed into a bi-quadratic equation so that you can use the simple expressions for the solutions of a quadratic equation.